# Scroll to bottom in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I want to scroll to the bottom of my scroll view when another comment is added to the chat. I tried using `ScrollViewReader` but it is not scrolling to the bottom. I'm checking if the comments are adding in the `onChange` method it is triggering and printing out the last index of the array. I am not sure why it wouldn't be working then

```
class TakeCommentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var comments = [TakeComment]()
}
```

in the SwiftUI File:

`@ObservedObject var model = TakeCommentViewModel()`

```
var commentsList: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    TakeTopView(dismissAction: dismissAction, take: take)
                    ForEach(model.comments) { comment in
                        TakeCommentView(comment: comment, viewModel: model)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                model.fetchComments(takeID: take.id)
                IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
                proxy.scrollTo(model.comments.count - 1, anchor: .top)
            }
            .onDisappear {
                if model.listener != nil {
                    model.listener.remove()
                }
                IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
            }
            .onChange(of: model.comments.count, perform: { value in
                proxy.scrollTo(model.comments.count - 1)
                let _ = print("CHANGED: \(model.comments.count)")

            })
        }   
    }
```

Comment: The `ScrollViewReader` probably expects an `id`. Does it work if you do `if let last = model.comments.last { proxy.scrollTo(last.id) }`?

Comment: as @jnpdx mentioned, ScrollViewReader expects an `id`, 
the `scrollTo` uses `id` not `index`, so you may want to add `id` after `TakeTopView(dismissAction: dismissAction, take: take)` and try again

Comment: I believe the `ForEach` will append the `id` automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `scrollTo` based on index, you need to set index as id.

```
ForEach(Array(model.comments.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, comment in
    TakeCommentView(comment: comment, viewModel: model)
        .id(index)  // ForEach might set id automatically, but I added this just in case
}
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you!